# Warning: Comparison between pointer and integer? Logic Errors?

Tags: c, warnings

I am trying to write a program that validates an area code using C. The user enters an area code and the program checks if it is valid. I am doing this with an array. When I run the program and enter a valid area code I get the return "Invalid area code." I think there is a problem with my logic.

Also when compiling I get `warning: comparison between pointer and integer`.

How could I fix this?

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int codeToCheck[4] = {303, 720, 970, 719};
    int codeToFind = 0;
    int i = 0;

    printf("Enter an area code to validate: ");
    scanf("%d", &codeToFind);

    for(i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
    {
        codeToCheck[i] = codeToFind;
        if(codeToFind == codeToCheck)
            break; 

    }

    if(codeToFind == codeToCheck)
        printf("\nValid Area Code in Colorado!");
    else
        printf("\nInvalid Area Code in Colorado");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: your for loop should run from 0 to 4, Moreover you can not compare ` if(codeToFind == codeToCheck)` since codeToCheck is an array and codeToFind is integer

Comment: In `C` array index starts from `0` you should run your for loop from `0` to `3` . like `for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your `if(codeToFind == codeToCheck)` statement, here you are checking the value of an integer with the base address of the array.

```
if(codeToFind == codeToCheck) //Correct comparison of array elements is codeTofind == codeToCheck[i]
```

Also your core logic is not correct, 
In the code posted by you the condition inside `if` will always be true because in the statement above `if` you are assigning `codeToCheck[i]` with `codeToFind` value, and in the next line you are comparing the same values!!

You can correct your code like this for correct output

```
 int flag = 0;
 for(i = 0; i <= 4; i++)  //You should also correct this line, array indices always starts from 0
    {
        if(codeToFind[i] == codeToCheck) 
        {
            flag = 1;
            break; 
        }
    }

    if(flag)
        printf("\nValid Area Code in Colorado!");
    else
        printf("\nInvalid Area Code in Colorado");
```

Answer (score 0):

Warning is due to  `if(codeToFind == codeToCheck)` where you are comparing a integer with base address of first element of array.

Remember, name of array decays to pointer to its first element.

Answer (score 0):

You mean to use `codeToCheck[i]` instead of `codeToCheck` in your `if` statement:

```
if(codeToFind == codeToCheck[i])
```

Also the assignment on the previous statement will make the comparison always true. You probably don't want to do that either.

Your `for` loop has incorrect bounds as well. Your current bounds for `i` will access `codeToCheck[4]` which is out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Try this=-

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int codeToCheck[4] = {303, 720, 970, 719};
    int codeToFind = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int flag=0;

   printf("Enter an area code to validate: ");
   scanf("%d", &codeToFind);

  for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
   {
      if(codeToFind == codeToCheck[i])
       {flag=1;
      break; 
       }

   }

   if(flag==1)
      printf("\nValid Area Code in Colorado!");
   else
      printf("\nInvalid Area Code in Colorado");

   return 0; 

}
}
```

Comment: @Dayalrai: Thanks for pointing that out. OP had done this mistake in two places, I corrected at one and forgot at the other place.

Comment: it will always print `Valid Area Code in Colorado!`

Comment: @prince: Corrected now.